# Elasticsearch Completion Suggester - Sort suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have the Elasticsearch completion suggester return the results in sorted order?  I'm following the example in [this Elasticsearch blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/) and added additional hotels:

```
{"name": "Mercure Hotel", "city": "Munich", "name_suggest": "Mercure Hotel"}
{"name": "Mercure Motel", "city": "Munich", "name_suggest": "Mercure Motel"}
{"name": "Mercure1", "city": "Munich", "name_suggest": "Mercure1"}
{"name": "Mercure2", "city": "Munich", "name_suggest": "Mercure2"}
{"name": "Mercure3", "city": "Munich", "name_suggest": "Mercure3"}
```

When I post the following to the _suggest endpoint...

```
{
  "hotels":
  {
    "text": "Me", "completion": {"field":"name_suggest", "size":10}
  }
}
```

...my results are ordered like so (all with score: 1):

- Mercure Motel
- Mercure Hotel Munich
- Mercure1
- Mercure2
- Mercure Hotel
- Mercure3

I'd like them to be sorted lexically, so "Mercure Hotel" comes before "Mercure Motel" at the very least.

The results are ordered the same even if I post the text "Mercure2" to _suggest.  My expectation is that Mercure2 would be the first suggestion, if not the only one.

When I don't find that others are having the same problem it usually means I'm doing something wrong or completely misunderstand the topic.  Am I expecting too much from the completion suggester or do I need to make a configuration change to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: don't you have to specify the `sort` clause?

Comment: The sort clause isn't supported by the _suggest endpoint. I tried using the _search endpoint but get an error 400 when I try to sort: "Sorting not supported for field[name_suggest]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `weight` to each document – the higher the number, the higher it's prioritized.

That is, sort your `output` strings lexically and then enumerate them. Finally, subtract their index from `2 ** 31 - 1` (the highest priority) to get suggestions in lexically ascending order.

Comment: What if I have a `geo_point` field and i want to sort based on the distance from a `geo_point` given at run time?